# File doesn't open in Fortran

Tags: debugging, fortran

```
      out_file3 = 'file1'
      OPEN(unit=3,file=out_file3,err=18, iostat=io_status)
 18   write(STDOUT,*) 'io status=', io_status
```

I'm trying to open a file and read it later on. But, the file just doesn't open and traceback points to the line `OPEN(unit=3,file=out_file3,err=18, iostat=io_status)` as the one causing error. I have tried changing unit values to > 10 if that has to do anything with the problem. But, all values seem to give an error.

Comment: What kimd of error message do you have? I wouldn't combine both err and iostat. What is the value of `io_status`? Is the unit already connected or not? We need much more information. And likely more code.

Comment: There is no error message as such, the traceback gives a pointer indicating the line number where the code stops. And the line number corresponds to `OPEN...`

Comment: How do I determine the appropriate unit value? That could be the problem.

Comment: Using inquiire or by using `newunit=`. But you could spend a week guessing. You should diagnose systematically. What is the value of those variables? What is the value of other variables?

Comment: Yes! It is a duplicate.

Comment: @VladimirF when you say variables, which variables are you referring to? out_file3 is already specified. I got rid of err=18. But, end up with the same result.

Comment: I asked about `io_status`. However, continue in the original question and add all the important info there.